# clang error: linker command failed with exit code 1104

Tags: c, windows, cmake, clang

Hi I'm rather new to Windows command prompt(have only been using Linux-based OS)

I'm trying to install OpenBLAS for Windows according to this [tutorial](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio).

When I tried running step 6

```
cmake .. -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=flang -DBUILD_WITHOUT_LAPACK=no -DNOFORTRAN=0 -DDYNAMIC_ARCH=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

I get the following error

> Compiling the C compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed. Compiler:
>   C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/bin/clang-cl.exe  Build flags:
>   /DWIN32;/D_WINDOWS;/W3 Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1104 LINK : fatal error LNK1104: ファイル 'libcmt.lib'
>   を開くことができません。 clang-cl.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1104 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/bin/ninja.exe"
>   "cmTC_e55c4" [1/2] Building C object
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_e55c4.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_e55c4.exe
>
> FAILED: cmTC_e55c4.exe
>
> cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\cmake.exe -E
>   vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_e55c4.dir --manifests  --
>   C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1415~1.267\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe
>   /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_e55c4.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj 
>   /out:cmTC_e55c4.exe /implib:cmTC_e55c4.lib /pdb:cmTC_e55c4.pdb
>   /version:0.0  /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console 
>   kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib
>   oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
>
> RC Pass 1: command "rc /foCMakeFiles\cmTC_e55c4.dir/manifest.res
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_e55c4.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the
>   following output:
>   隰悶・・ｮ螢ｹ・・ｹｧ蠕娯螺郢晁ｼ斐＜郢ｧ・､郢晢ｽｫ邵ｺ迹夲ｽｦ荵昶命邵ｺ荵晢ｽ顔ｸｺ・ｾ邵ｺ蟶呻ｽ鍋ｸｲ繝ｻ ninja: build
>   stopped: subcommand failed.

Random but also,I don't know why it's outputting Chinese characters in the end...(my system language is set to Japanese and not Chinese)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer - you should also add -DCMAKE_RC_COMPILER=llvm-rc (don't remember correct name)